# Firefox css3 animations

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have heard of hacks and tricks that can be done to implement css3 animations in firefox. I did some research and came to nothing. Do any of you here know how to implement css3 animations in firefox and opera (and IE if possible)? I'll really appreciate it! Thanks!

EDIT:

```
 #pictureMove {
    -webkit-animation:pictureTransition 25s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -moz-animation-name:pictureTransition;
    -moz-animation-duration::25s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function:linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pictureTransition {
    from,5% {-webkit-transform:translateX(0px);-moz-transform:translate(0px);}
    10%,25% {-webkit-transform:translateX(-1024px);-moz-transform:translate(-1024px);}
    30%,45% {-webkit-transform:translateX(-2048px);-moz-transform:translate(-2048px);}
    50%,65% {-webkit-transform:translateX(-3072px);-moz-transform:translate(-3072px);}
    70%,85% {-webkit-transform:translateX(-4096px);-moz-transform:translate(-4096px);}
    90%,to {-webkit-transform:translateX(-5120px);-moz-transform:translate(-5120px);}
}
@-moz-keyframes pictureTransition {
    from,5% {-moz-transform:translateX(0px);}
    10%,25% {-moz-transform:translateX(-1024px);}
    30%,45% {-moz-transform:translateX(-2048px);}
    50%,65% {-moz-transform:translateX(-3072px);}
    70%,85% {-moz-transform:translateX(-4096px);}
    90%,to {-moz-transform:translateX(-5120px);}
}
```

Comment: Firefox already supports like 90% of all of the CSS3 animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox supports animations:

Specifically CSS transitions are supported in Firefox 4+ and keyframes in Firefox 5+

***Docs:***

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@keyframes

***Examples:***

- http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/05/advanced-animations-in-aurora-with-css3-animations/
- http://paulrouget.com/e/css3animations/

Comment: can u look at this for a while in firefox? http://anywearstyle.com/ is the one used there css3 animations? because -moz-animation does not work on my current firefox but that worked

Comment: @AJNaidas can you be more specific about what you have tried, and what is not working. Perhaps create a JSFiddle of it.

Comment: @AJNaidas well it maybe because you have `@-webkit-keyframes` but no `@-moz-keyframes`

Comment: re edited according to your second example. It didn't work for me for some reason. Firefox version is 9.0.1.

Comment: @AJNaidas , 3D transformations have been introduced only with Firefox 10. see http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/10.0.1/releasenotes/ and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=505115